# Direct sums producing the vector space R->R

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, exponential-function, solution-verification, direct-sum

An exercise in my assignment asks for the following proof.

Prove that the vector space R->R is equal to the direct sum of:

- the set of real valued even functions on R Ue
- the set of real valued odd functions on R Uo

Investigating this question I seem to have found a counter example f(x)= e^x.

This is because f(-x) = 1/e^x which is neither even or odd.

Can someone please clarify if I'm mistaken or if the exercise is wrong?

Comment: What is the vector space?

Comment: But $e^x=\cosh x+\sinh x$, and $\cosh x$ is even, $\sinh x$ is odd. $V=U_o\oplus U_e$ does not mean that $V=U_o\cup U_e$,

Comment: What is "$\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? The space of arbitrary functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Continuous ones? Linear ones (i.e., $\Hom(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Set of Real valued functions mapping real numbers to real numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a counter example, since$$e^x=\overbrace{\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2}^{\text{even function}}+\overbrace{\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2}^{\text{odd function}}.$$

Comment: This confuses me, because you're using e^x to define e^x. Seems a bit circular. What also confused me is that the sum of an even functions an odd function is odd. But looking at the graph of e^x we can see it's neither even or odd. Also see here :  https://www.quora.com/Is-e-x-an-odd-or-an-even-function

Comment: No, I am **not**. I am expressing $e^x$ as the sum of an even function with an odd function. At no point I defined the meaning of $e^x$.

Comment: Apologies I did not mean to offend. I just mean that the graph of the function and other explanations point to e^x being not even or odd.

Comment: Of course it's neither even nor odd. And… ? Asserting that the space $\mathcal F$ of all functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ is the direct sum of the space of all even functions with the space of all odd functions just means that every element of $\mathcal F$ can be written in one and only one way as the sum of an even function with an odd one. It does **not** mean that every element of $\mathcal F$ is either even or odd.

Comment: Ahah! Thanks alot man! I see where my reasoning was wrong now.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I've done so. Thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Taylor series for $e^x$: $e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then $e^x$ is the sum of the even and odd functions $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}$. Now what are those functions explicitly?

Comment: This is a power series, so the cardinality of the number of expressions is infinite. So we can't say anything about the evenness or oddness of the function from that series I think.

Comment: You can, and even if you couldn’t you could find the functions (hyperbolic sine/cosine) that they are the Taylor series of.